# Replacing values in a data frame column

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

Given a large data frame with a column that has unique values

(ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT)

I want to replace some of the values.  For example, every occurrence of 'ONE' should be replaced by '1' and

```
'FOUR' -> '2SQUARED'
'FIVE' -> '5'
'EIGHT' -> '2CUBED'
```

Other values should remain as they are.

IF/ELSE will run forever.  How to apply a vectorized solution? Is match() the corrct way to go?

Comment: Check `mapvalues` in `plyr` package

Comment: I think this is the best solution so far since I said it is a large data frame.  I have many subs to do so creating 2 vectors replace = c(...) and with = c(...) to use in mapvalues() is easiest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @rnso data set

```
library(plyr)
transform(data, vals = mapvalues(vals, 
          c('ONE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE', 'EIGHT'),
          c('1','2SQUARED', '5', '2CUBED'))) 
#       vals
# 1        1
# 2      TWO
# 3    THREE
# 4 2SQUARED
# 5        5
# 6      SIX
# 7    SEVEN
# 8   2CUBED
```

Comment: I used mapvalues and it did exactly what I wanted.  Thanks

Comment: @MaxWen - you're going to load a library just to change factors?  Did you see my answer?

Comment: @RichardScriven Yes I saw it but I had completed my project by the time I did.  You are correct the column is a factor and your solution looks like it would work.  And normally I would rather not load a library, but I don't mind here since I need to learn more about plyr.  I would upvote your solution but I lack the rep to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try following using base R:

```
data = structure(list(vals = structure(c(4L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 
1L), .Label = c("EIGHT", "FIVE", "FOUR", "ONE", "SEVEN", "SIX", 
"THREE", "TWO"), class = "factor")), .Names = "vals", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

initial = c('ONE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE', 'EIGHT')
final = c('1','2SQUARED', '5', '2CUBED')

myfn = function(ddf, init, fin){
    refdf = data.frame(init,fin)
    ddf$new = refdf[match(ddf$vals, init), 'fin']
    ddf$new = as.character(ddf$new)
    ndx = which(is.na(ddf$new))
    ddf$new[ndx]= as.character(ddf$vals[ndx])
    ddf
}

myfn(data, initial, final)

   vals      new
1   ONE        1
2   TWO      TWO
3 THREE    THREE
4  FOUR 2SQUARED
5  FIVE        5
6   SIX      SIX
7 SEVEN    SEVEN
8 EIGHT   2CUBED
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your column is probably a `factor`. Give this a try. Using rnso's `data`, I'd recommend you first create two vectors of values to change from and values to change to

```
from <- c("FOUR", "FIVE", "EIGHT")
to <- c("2SQUARED", "5", "2CUBED")
```

Then replace the factors with

```
with(data, levels(vals)[match(from, levels(vals))] <- to)
```

This gives

```
data
#       vals
# 1      ONE
# 2      TWO
# 3    THREE
# 4 2SQUARED
# 5        5
# 6      SIX
# 7    SEVEN
# 8   2CUBED
```